# git get ubuntu kernel source through http proxy

Tags: proxy, git

I try to run below command to get kernel source code in ubuntu 12.04.

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git
```

As my machine is in a private network, I need setup a http proxy to access the public network. But even I run the command below, git still can't get the code. Could anyone let me know how to setup the http proxy for git?

```
git config --global http.proxy http://<my proxy server>:80
```

Regards,
CY.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got the answer from
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/KernelGitGuide

I can use the http protocol to do clone.

git clone http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git/